# Connecting to SQL Server using Windows authentication (other than my local one, in different domain) from Powershell script in Jenkins

Tags: sql-server, powershell, jenkins, windows-authentication

I need to query two databases from Jenkins to compare the returned results.
The first one is the SQL Server database where only Windows authentication is enabled.
The mentioned account that I use to authenticate is different than that I use on machine with Jenkins.

I thought about writing a Powershell script to do that, because there's a Powershell plugin for Jenkins.
Most solutions that I've found suggest either using `runas` Windows command or start a new `Powershell` process (https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/427e768b-a11b-4da3-abeb-131d26557d63/running-powershell-as-a-specific-user?forum=ITCG).

However, as I understand, this opens completely new Powershell window/console and the next commands that I typed in Powershell Jenkins build step will be still executed in previous Powershell console, not the one with different user.
Is there any workaround? Is it possible to "transfer" commands to this new Powershell process?

Similar question was asked on SO ([How can I connect to SQL through PowerShell using Windows authentication other than my local one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37556726/how-can-i-connect-to-sql-through-powershell-using-windows-authentication-other-t)), but it doesn't help on my case (the mentioned question was not about running from Jenkins).

Answer (score 0):

I assume your Jenkins on Windows.

Possible workarounds are

Whatever Windows account is used to run Jenkins service, grant the permission on SQL server, ever system service you can grant the computer object to SQL server.

OR

Store a credential in Jenkins, run powershell job like following, of course you will need to well-set Jenkins job to use the credential.

[image]

```
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($env:user, (ConvertTo-SecureString $env:pass -AsPlainText -Force))
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "localhost or SQL server, or any other windows" -Credential $credential -ScriptBlock {Invoke-SqlCommand XXXXXXXXXXX}
```

Comment: The second solution fails, because of lack of WinRM configured (I assume that it must be configured on target machine and I woul like to not change this environment):

Comment: Connecting to remote server X.X.X.X failed with the following error message : The WinRM client cannot process the request. Default authentication may be used with an IP address under the following conditions: the transport is HTTPS or the destination is in the TrustedHosts list, and explicit credentials are provided. Use winrm.cmd to configure TrustedHosts. Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated. For more information on how to set TrustedHosts run the following command: winrm help config. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic

Comment: @matandked don't use ip address unless you well-configure winrm on https protocol or this ip address is a trustedhost. use dns name instead.